# How can I bypass NSWindowSharingNone to take screenshots, etc.?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

If an app does `[window setSharingType: NSWindowSharingNone];`, normal methods of taking screenshots won't work for it. As the administrator of a Mac, how can I override this and capture its screen anyway? I'm willing to disable SIP to do so if necessary.

Comment: That's an attribute of the app's code, which has been compiled into binary data. You can't realistically change this, regardless of whether you're an administrator or not, short of reverse engineering the binary and finding out which byte sequence describes that property. You may be better off seeing if there's some low-level way of getting the pixel data from a screen area, or similar.

Comment: @benwiggy I was less interested in "how do I make the app not set NSWindowSharingNone" and more interested in "how do I make macOS not respect NSWindowSharingNone" anyway.

Comment: That would require modifying some binary in the OS in a similarly non-trivial manner. As said, you might be better off with a different approach to your problem. But there's not going to be a straightforward, simple list of instructions: Apple doesn't want you to copy certain content.